# Decreasing default cursor size before entered text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have some input boxes that are getting different results from different browsers. Here is the css for the boxes:

```
.InputBox
{
    background-image: url(../text_field.png);
    height: 25px;
    width: 192px;
    z-index:300;
    position:absolute;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I assumed to make the cursor match the size/location of the text box I would only need to add the `padding` and the `font-size` calls. Unfortunately this is not the case. As of now here is the issues I am having by browser

**Chrome** None

**Safari** None

**IE8** Cursor WAY to high, does not show up in front of box until text it typed. Text is not centered, but closer to the top

**Firefox** Cursor size is to big when no text is entered. Once text is entered cursor is fine. If text is deleted cursor becomes to big.

How do you adjust initial cursor size in Firefox? I was assuming it would match `font-size`, but I guess that is not the case. Also, how could I adjust the `padding` in IE without changing it in others, and why would the cursor show up behind the text box when no text is entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug which I have fixed in Firefox 4.  In Firefox 4, the cursor size is always the size of the text which is going to be entered.  We take that size from the font-size property.  In Firefox 3.6 and earlier versions, the size is determined by the height of the block containing the cursor, if it doesn't have any text inside it.

Comment: I thought it was based on the height. The only issue there is how do I edit the height without removing part of my textbox? Its a `background-image` so cutting the height down will cut part of the box off

Comment: You can try decreasing `height` and compensating for the correct position by adjusting the `margin` (most likely `margin-top`) property.